# "html transition" reset php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

In the top of my page (laravel blade template) I've some script mixed from javascript/php enclosed in blade's php tag:

```
    @php
            $numDomande=12;
            $optionInseriteStampa=[];
            for($c=1;$c<=$numDomande;$c++){
                  array_push($optionInseriteStampa,"<option value=\"$c\">'$c'</option>");
            }
    @endphp
            <script>
                var optionInserite= new Array();
                var kk=1;
                var numeroDomande={!! $numDomande !!};
                for(c=1;c<=numeroDomande; c++){
                    console.log(kk);
                    optionInserite.push('<option value="'+kk+'">'+kk+'</option>');
                    kk++;
                }

            </script>
```

Then my page HTML starts and the value is available  (I've checked it with some silly `{{dd($optionInseriteStampa)}}` untill this tag:

```
<div id="smartwizard" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

After this tag my php variable disappears and it isn't usable any more.

This tag is the starting point for this wizard structure:
http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard/documentation

And I've put it to be hidden -as you can see from the tag itself-, then inside a script a call those lines:

```
$('#smartwizard').css('visibility','visible');
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
```

I cant really understand if its a problem about the plugin or the css transition from visible to hidden.

Thanks.

Comment: Please always take some time to format the question properly so it's easier to read and more valuable to future readers.

Comment: yes thanks for edits

Comment: What does "my php variable disappears" mean?

Comment: thats is no longer available for the page...

Comment: You mean to say the variable give its value above that tag and don't show anything below that tag?

Comment: @HaiderAli extacly, if I use again the silly {{dd()}} not printed (ok all the div is not visible) but even if I use it for printing after the transition is still not aviable

Comment: have you tried checking it in page source?

Comment: I've edited the code to be more simple and separated, but same purpose, same results... not works. in the source of the page I can see just the script part and seem like static text